# Pushing values to array adds undefined at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, firebase

I am pulling data from Firebase. I want to extract values and save them in the array. After that I will use that array values as strings in my application. The problem is when I push values from DB to array, it adds undefined at the end of the array. And when I want to see the value of array (carUserDetails[0]) it returns undefined, but should return a string "BMW"

```
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var refModels = firebase.database().ref("/users/" + UserID);

var carUserDetails = [];

refModels.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var usersValue = childSnapshot.val(); //get the values of the object
        carUserDetails.push(
            usersValue.carMake, 
            usersValue.carYear, 
            usersValue.carModel, 
            usersValue.carTrim
        );
    });
});

console.log(carUserDetails);
```

[image]

```
console.log(carUserDetails[0]) // returns undefined too
```

So what could be the problem

Comment: Check if your loop is executing 2 times. And then in second iteration usersValue.carMake can be undefined

Comment: What do you get if you print `snapshot`?

Comment: add a console.log just after push to print uservalue and see what it prints probably your loop executing twice. and you are getting carUserDetails[0 undefined  because of Asynchronous code execution

Comment: After I console log after the push it print out twice. So looks like it executes twice. and how to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

So yes it an asynchronous call issue. See the fix

```
var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var refModels = firebase.database().ref("/users/" + UserID);

var carUserDetails = [];

refModels.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var usersValue = childSnapshot.val(); //get the values of the object
    carUserDetails.push(
        usersValue.carMake, 
        usersValue.carYear, 
        usersValue.carModel, 
        usersValue.carTrim
      );
     });

     $scope.getValueFromArray(); //call function here

    });



$scope.getValueFromArray = function(){

   console.log(carUserDetails[0]); returns "BMW"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are too early calling `console.log` remember reading firebase value is asynchronous. You should put your console, inside `function (snapshot)` and after `snapshot.forEach`

```
refModels.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    ....
  });
  console.log(carUserDetails);
});
```